# ObjectMapper writeValueAsString changes bytebuffer pos

Tags: java

I am trying to serialize a complex object to string that somewhere contains bytebuffer inside by using ObjectMapper for logging the response.
This changes the cursor position inside the bytebuffer and simply corrupts the response.

Code snippet that i am using:

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

private static final ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

public static String serializeToString(final Object obj) {
    Preconditions.checkArgument(obj != null, "Object to be serialized is null");
    try {
        final String str = MAPPER.writeValueAsString(obj);
        if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(str)) {
            log.warn("Serialized to null/empty string");
        }
        return str;
    } catch (final JsonGenerationException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Json generation exception occured in de-serializing obj", e);
    } catch (final JsonMappingException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Json mapping exception occured in de-serializing obj", e);
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("IO exception occured in de-serializing obj", e);
    }
}
```

I passed above method a complex object having bytebuffer inside.
I printed bytebuffer before and after calling above method.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException {
    final String x =
            "Random data i am using for this test for byte buffer. Random data i am using for this test for byte buffer";
    final byte[] byteArr = x.getBytes();
    final ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArr);
    System.out.println("before bytebuffer :" + bb);
    String stringData = SerializerUtil.serializeToString(bb); // In real i am passing a complex structure having
                                                              // bytebuffer inside
    System.out.println(stringData);
    System.out.println("after bytebuffer :" + bb);
}
```

Output:

```
before bytebuffer :java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=106 cap=106]

{"short":21089,"char":"\u6e64","int":1869422692,"long":7022344510808023405,"float":2.0790493E-19,"double":6.687717052371733E223,"direct":false,"readOnly":false}

after bytebuffer :java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=28 lim=106 cap=106]
```

This change in (pos=0 to pos=28)position simply corrupts the response sent. Do we have any way to convert this complex object to string without affecting the byteBuffer?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, you don't want to serialize the `ByteBuffer` property as another structured class, but just the content, as a string. One way to do that is to use a `@JsonProperty` annotation on a method to tell the mapper to use that method instead of trying to serialize the field directly. Assuming you have a bean like this:

```
class Stuff {

    private ByteBuffer data;

    public Stuff() {
    }

    public Stuff(ByteBuffer data) {
        super();
        this.data = data;
    }

    public ByteBuffer getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(ByteBuffer data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @JsonProperty(value = "data")
    public String convertData() {
        return new String(data.array());
    }

    @JsonProperty("data")
    public void convertData(String s) {
        data = ByteBuffer.wrap(s.getBytes());
    }

}
```

The mapper will now use the convertData methods for serializeing and deserializing the ByteBuffer data property, and you can still use normal java bean property methods.

*Update*:

Since the serialized class cannot be changed, here is an alternative method using som advanced JACKSON stuff. First, create custom serializer and deserializer:

```
static class ByteBufferSerializer extends JsonSerializer<ByteBuffer> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(ByteBuffer value, JsonGenerator jgen,
            SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException,
            JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeString(new String(value.array()));
    }
}

static class ByteBufferDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<ByteBuffer> {

    @Override
    public ByteBuffer deserialize(JsonParser jp,
            DeserializationContext context) throws IOException,
            JsonProcessingException {
        return ByteBuffer.wrap(jp.getText().getBytes());
    }

}
```

Then, create a Mixin interface to provide the annotations for the properties that we cannot provide in the real target class:

```
static interface Mixin {

    @JsonSerialize(using = ByteBufferSerializer.class, contentAs = String.class)
    ByteBuffer getData();

    @JsonDeserialize(using = ByteBufferDeserializer.class, contentAs = String.class)
    void setData(ByteBuffer data);

}
```

Further, create a Module used to configure the object mapper, and add the mixin interface:

```
static class MyModule extends SimpleModule {
    public MyModule() {
        super("ByteBuffer wrangling");
    }

    @Override
    public void setupModule(SetupContext context) {
        context.setMixInAnnotations(Stuff.class, Mixin.class);
    }
}
```

And, finally, register the module with the mapper:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.registerModule(new MyModule());
```

Voilà, piece of cake! :-)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but my complex response object is WSDL generated, so can't add this JSON property around that ByteBuffer data.

Comment: A ByteBuffer in a WSDL? Yeah, well, that's "innovative", if nothing else.

Comment: Basically we call it "blob", but it's generated as byteBuffer for smoother data transfer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this perfectly fits with my requirement. 
Some how 
    context.setMixInAnnotations(Stuff.class, Mixin.class);
didn't work for me. I am using the following 
SimpleModule.addSerializer(ByteBuffer.class, new ByteBufferSerializer());
Thanks :)